# can't install module Azsk CI / CD pipeline when azure devops is installing the module

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have [Azsk](https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit-docs) implemented in my azure devops pipeline. Before anything works finely and i can run the pipeline normally. i didn't changed anything but it gave me this error atm

```
2018-12-14T10:41:12.7861566Z Installing Module AzSK...
2018-12-14T10:41:58.9483761Z ##[error]Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'InstalledModuleInfo'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Management.Automation.PSModuleInfo".
2018-12-14T10:41:58.9850394Z ##[section]Finishing: AzSK_SVTs
```

Google got me to this : https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/2357
But this will update the module on my local machine, while the problem is the installation of the module in my pipeline (some kind of container that azure devops is running).

Anyone have this issue lately or does know how to fix this ?

Comment: Are you installing azsk through PS?

Comment: Theoretically yes.
I add the AzSK module to my pipeline. When the pipeline runs it starts a small terminal some kind of environment azure devops set up, and their it installs ad hoc the module

Comment: Are you building a .net core app?

Comment: No I'm not  , i deploy security testing for my azure environment. and tried to automate it with the azsk security test tool in azure devops

Comment: what build task are you using for this? PowerShell or Azure PowerShell

Comment: the build task is "Azsk" out of the box. this is not being installed with some powershell commands in my pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official Azsk GitHub:](https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit-docs/tree/master/00a-Setup#error-message-packagemanagementinstall-package-cannot-process-argument-transformation-on-parameter-installedmoduleinfo)

**Error message: "PackageManagement\Install-Package: cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'InstalledModuleInfo'..."**

If you have installed AzureRM PowerShell using Azure SDK in your machine, it typically get installed in Program Files. You could run the below command to confirm

```
Get-Module -Name AzureRM* -ListAvailable
```

If this is the case, then you need to remove the Azure PowerShell modules installed through Azure SDK completely from the Program Files. You could also take back up in case if you need. AzSK also need AzureRM modules. But it would download from PSGallery instead of from Azure SDK. This downloading of AzureRM modules from PS Gallery would conflict with AzureRM modules installed through Azure SDK. After cleanup, If you again the run the below command, it would fetch AzureRM version 5.2.0 by default into the current user scope instead of in Program Files.

```
Install-Module AzSK -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber
```

In case you still need to use the other version of AzureRm (that you removed), you can install it from PS Gallery using the command below:

```
Install-Module AzureRM -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber -RequiredVersion <versionNumber e.g. “3.8.0” >
```

*Note: If "-AllowClobber" option is not available in your version of PS, then replace that with "-Force"*

If you happen to have multiple versions of AzureRM, then it depends on which version of the module loads first in the PS session. In that case, to avoid confusion, close the installer PS session and in a new PS session run the following first:

```
Import-Module AzSK
```

Then you can run one or more AzSK commands or other AzureRm commands. The "Import-Module" ensures that the right version of AzureRM gets loaded into the current session.

**So in your case that is Hosted agent, try add PowerShell task before the Azsk task and run the commands above.**